# How to substitute variables into JQuery selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have HTML:

```
<li onclick="myselect(mazda3,m3-to);">...</li>
```

and function:

```
var a='';
var b='';
function myselect(a,b){
    $('#workcont').empty();
    $('#tocont').load('pages/' + a + '.html #' + b);
}
```

But it's not work. How to improve it?

Comment: at least you have to use strings in `onclick` handler: `onclick="myselect('mazda3','m3-to');"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you meant for `mazda3` and `m3-to` to be strings:

```
onclick="myselect('mazda3', 'm3-to');"
```